# How to disable lazy loads on a newly-persisted SQLAlchemy 2.0 model?

Tags: sqlalchemy, relationship

I have a routine that accepts an instance of a SQLAlchemy model. One thing that it does is look at the number of child objects. This works fine if I have loaded the model through the ORM's select() function with eager-loading of the related records; however, when I create a new object, persist it, and then pass it to the consuming function, because I am out of the session scope I get a DetachedInstanceError. How can I disable the behavior on a newly-persisted instance?

Example code:

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Customer(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'customers'

    customer_id: str = Column(String(36), primary_key=True)
    orders: Mapped['Order'] = relationship('Order', back_populates='customer')


class Order(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'orders'

    order_id: str = Column(String(36), primary_key=True)
    customer_id: str = Column(String(36), ForeignKey('customers.customer_id'))

    customer: Mapped['Customer'] = relationship('Customer', back_populates='orders')


customer = Customer()
print(customer.orders)  # Works fine

session.add(customer)

print(customer.orders)  # Uh-oh
```

Comment: If you do not want lazy load, disable it? `orders: Mapped['Order'] = relationship('Order', back_populates='customer', lazy='noload')`?

Comment: depending on your use-case you may also need to do this when you create the session, `Session(expire_on_commit=False)` or if you use session maker then `Session = sessionmaker(expire_on_commit=False)`

Comment: That’s what I was looking for! lazy=‘noload’ did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Disable lazy loading:

```
orders: Mapped['Order'] = relationship('Order', back_populates='customer', lazy='noload')
```